# counter to track the number of times a user has used a feature - android

Tags: android, firebase

I'm making an app that starts with a splash activity and somewhere in its some other activity requires a counter to track the number of times a user has used a particular feature. This counter should have all the counts since when the user had registered to my app for the very first time. I want to store this counter to firebase and not use shared preferences as the value will be lost the moment the user uninstalls the app. Could someone please suggest a method here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Shared Preference to this job.
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences